# My Meteor app crashes whenever I include a <head>

Tags: meteor

After upgrading from Meteor 0.8.3 to Meteor 1.0 (and migrating all necessary packages), my app won't start normally anymore. It just crashes shortly after startup with the error:

```
I20141110-23:58:20.541(1)? Exception in queued task: Error: ENOENT, open '../web.browser/head.html'
I20141110-23:58:20.541(1)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/leo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
I20141110-23:58:20.541(1)?     at _.extend.runTask (packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:79)
I20141110-23:58:20.542(1)?     at Object.WebAppInternals.generateBoilerplate (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:588)
I20141110-23:58:20.542(1)?     at updateVersions (packages/autoupdate/autoupdate_server.js:89)
I20141110-23:58:20.542(1)?     at Object.task (packages/autoupdate/autoupdate_server.js:183)
I20141110-23:58:20.542(1)?     at _.extend._run (packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:145)
I20141110-23:58:20.542(1)?     at packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:123
I20141110-23:58:20.543(1)?     - - - - -
I20141110-23:58:20.543(1)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/leo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
I20141110-23:58:20.543(1)?     at packages/meteor/helpers.js:118
I20141110-23:58:20.543(1)?     at readUtf8FileSync (packages/boilerplate-generator/boilerplate-generator.js:6)
I20141110-23:58:20.543(1)?     at packages/boilerplate-generator/boilerplate-generator.js:81
I20141110-23:58:20.544(1)?     at Array.forEach (native)
I20141110-23:58:20.544(1)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105)
I20141110-23:58:20.544(1)?     at Boilerplate._generateBoilerplateFromManifestAndSource (packages/boilerplate-generator/boilerplate-generator.js:63)
I20141110-23:58:20.545(1)?     at new Boilerplate (packages/boilerplate-generator/boilerplate-generator.js:16)
I20141110-23:58:20.545(1)?     at Object.WebAppInternals.generateBoilerplateInstance (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:329)
I20141110-23:58:20.545(1)?     at packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:591
I20141110-23:58:20.546(1)?     - - - - -
```

So, apparently it complains about being unable to access `../web.browser/head.html`.

However, `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/head.html` *does* exist and contains `<head>`'s body:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="apps.css">
```

It is the same as the `<head>` in `client/main.html`.

If I remove the `<head>` element or make it empty, `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/head.html` will disappear, and *so will this crash*. However, I do need the `<head>` since it includes some essential tags and stylesheets.

This issue is definitely not related to the content of `<head>` since even a `<meta charset="utf-8">` will cause the crash. It seems to crash whenever there's a non-empty `<head>` element. That is, whenever there is a `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/head.html` file, which Meteor says is missing, ironically.

`head.html`'s permissions seem to be correct: -r--r--r--, which allows everyone to read the file. The file creation date also changes every time Meteor is "building the application".

So far, I know this issue happens with Meteor 0.9 or newer. The app worked perfectly fine under 0.8.3 prior to the migration.

I've also tried with a test project (`meteor create test`) and having a `<head>` works. Even having multiple `<head>`s in different HTML client files works, leading me to believe it is some weird issue caused by migrating my project.

This can't be reproduced in another test project using the same packages as the broken project.

Any ideas? I've tried debugging but debugging Meteor's code is way too complex for me.

Comment: Looks a bit like a meteor bug. Can you reproduce with a minimal repo? Also, does it crash only when there are more than one `head` sections across all client files?

Comment: What permissions does the file have?

Comment: @solarc I've updated the post with more information.

Answer (score 1):

After several more hours of debugging, I've found the culprit.

I had a server-side script (in server/) that used `shelljs` to `cd` into another directory.

While this worked fine under Meteor 0.8, it seems that changes in Meteor 0.9 make `cd`ing into other directories impossible, since it would break Meteor's internal components.

Although it is not exactly a Meteor bug, it is something that breaks compatibility and that hasn't been mentioned in the release notes... but then, I guess using `cd` is not something that can be found in most projects.

This also explains why Meteor only complains when there's a `<head>`. When there is no `<head>`, it won't try to read the file so everything is fine. However, when there's one, it will try to read the file and fails because the current directory is different from the one Meteor expects.

So, if you are having weird issues with Meteor and are using `shelljs`, make sure you're **not** using `cd`.